# Is the has_may relationship on rails necessary or the belong_to is enough?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with a var reference to another one.

```
User -> Profile
```

When I have generated the Profile model I used the references
feature so it has generated the corresponding migration

```
....
t.references :user
....
```

My question is do I have to add a relationship on the User model too?

```
has_one :Profile
```

Comment: Your relationship must be lower-case, `:profile`, not `:Profile`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need both code in two models and the migration you mentioned.

```
class User < AR
  has_one :profile
end

class Profile < AR
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Otherwise the association will not work, not to say foreign records :)

Answer (score 1):

has_one and belongs_to are just methods which adds some more methods to your model. This means, you can have belongs_to defined on one model and no has_one on the other. The only problem is that you would be able to call profile.user, but no user.profile.

It is absolutely up to you which methods you want to be defined and which you don't need. If you never ever want anyone to call profile.user, but want user.profile just call `has_one :profile`. In general those method shares nothing except that their using same foreign key column.

It is however worth mentioning, that this is usually advised to declare reverse association - it is not needed for things to work though.